# How to write following formulas in r?

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I need to write the following formulas in R. The STAT formula is copying effects of `oneway.test`-function.

[image: STAT formula]

where sample variance is

[image: Sample variance]

and

[image]

The variables are: `m` - number of samples, `n` - sample size, vector `sample_means` - mean of each sample and vector `sample_vars` - sample variance of each sample.

I'm trying to work with the following code, but it doesn't give the correct results when I compare it to `aov`:

```
my_anova <- function(m, n, sample_means, sample_vars) {
 
overall_mean <- mean(sample_means)

sample_vars <- sum((sample_means - overall_mean)^2)/(m-1)

STAT <- (n*sample_vars)/(sum(sample_vars/m))
  
  PVAL <- pf(STAT, m - 1, m*(n - 1), lower.tail = FALSE)
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure where you obtained the formulas above, but from what I can gather, you want to obtain the F stats and p value for a one way anova. n should be the degree of freedom and not sample size. Try using this [table](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/ppc/section2/ppc231.htm):

[image]

So bottom line is SSF should always be the sum of residuals between your predicted mean and overall mean, whereas SSE is the sum of residuals between your predicted mean and actual values. Then you divide by the corresponding degree of freedom. It should be like below:

```
my_aov <- function(sample_values, sample_means,n){
  
  overall_mean = mean(sample_values)
  SSF = sum((sample_means - overall_mean)^2)
  SSE = sum((sample_values - sample_means)^2)

  DoF = c(n,length(sample_values)-1-n)

  Mean_Square = c(SSF/DoF[1] , SSE/DoF[2])
  
  FSTAT = c(Mean_Square[1]/Mean_Square[2],NA)
  
  PVAL <- pf(FSTAT, DoF[1], DoF[2], lower.tail = FALSE)

  cbind(Sum_of_Squares= c(SSF,SSE),DoF,Mean_Square,FSTAT,PVAL)

}
```

Using an example:

```
values = iris$Sepal.Length
Species_values = tapply(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Species,mean)
predicted_values = Species_values[as.character(iris$Species)]
# since there are 3 groups, degree of freedom is 3-1
n = length(unique(iris$Species)) - 1

my_aov(values,predicted_values,n)

    Sum_of_Squares DoF Mean_Square    FSTAT         PVAL
[1,]       63.21213   2  31.6060667 119.2645 1.669669e-31
[2,]       38.95620 147   0.2650082       NA           NA
```

Compare with:

```
summary(aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species,data=iris))
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Species       2  63.21  31.606   119.3 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   147  38.96   0.265                   
---
```

Comment: Thanks! These are from Ross' Statistics book. He gives and explanation of **m - samples and n - size of sample**. The degrees of freedom for sample variance are m-1 and n-1 (m − 1 numerator and m(n − 1) denominator degrees of freedom)